# Right way of writing and loading modules in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I write node.js modules like this:

```
//MyModule.js
function MyModule() {
  ...somecode
}

MyModule.prototype.someFunc = function() {...}
module.exports = MyModule
```

However, when I need to use the module, I have to write something like this:

```
//main.js
var MyModule = require('MyModule');
var myModule = new MyModule();
```

This seems terribly ugly. Isn't there some way to do something like this

```
//main.js
var myModule = require('MyModule').new();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  (except that you need to export the constructor) What don't you like?

Comment: "This seems terribly ugly" 

Welcome to prototypical JavaScript.

Comment: @SLaks I would like to have something that generates the object automatically, instead of wasting a parameter

Comment: Something like .new() isn't typical but it can be achieved by creating a .new() method which returns a fresh instance of MyModule

Comment: If all you want is to drop the other variable you could do `var myModule = new (require('MyModule'))();` Or is that also ugly?

Comment: Or have module.exports return `new MyModule()`.

Comment: @tandrewnichols Unfortunately that won't quite do, as `require("MyModule")` will return the same instance of MyModule each time it is invoked. This is because Node.js caches modules the first time they are loaded

Answer (score 2):

quick hack for something not ugly

module.js

```
function MyModule() {
    console.dir('constructor');
}
module.exports = MyModule;
```

app.js

```
Function.prototype.new = function () {
    return new this();
};
var MyModule = require('./module.js').new(); // 'constructor'
```

Comment: +1 for the clever solution, but it should come with a warning about extending native objects

Answer (score 1):

If your module consists solely of functions, it may not need to be created as an instance - just define your module as being an object filled with functions. Like so:

```
var MyModule = {
  prepareHtmlContent: function() {
  },
  autoLoadActionInitiatorFunctions: function() {
  }
};
```

The reason I suggest this is that you've referred to your object as 'MyModule'. If your intent is specifically to use it as a 'Class', and instantiate separate copies of it when they're needed, then you're doing it the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use

```
(function(module) {

    module.myFunction = function() {

    }

    module.createSomeObj = function() {
        return {
           foo: 1,
           bar: 'bar'
        };       
    }

}(module.exports));
```

Usage

```
var myModule = require('./myModule');

myModule.myFunction();
var myObject = myModule.createSomeObj();
```